# Combining line plots (with data from DataFrames)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

Cant figure out how to combine these two plots.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%pylab inline #Jupyter Notebook


df_state.head()
lm_orginal_plot.head()
```

[outputs for .head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQuHN.png)

```
df_state.loc['Alabama'][['month','total purchases',
                         'permit','permit_recheck']].plot(x='month',figsize=(6,3),linestyle='-', marker='o')
lm_original_plot.plot(x='month',figsize=(6,3),linestyle=':');
```

[outputs for plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwdkj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how I would do this (not saying it is the best method or anything):
>
> 1) merge two dfs on month
>
> ```
> all = df_state(lm_original_plot, on = 'month', how='left')
> ```
>
> 2) create figure (total is now column just like the other variables in
>   the first chart, so you can just add ‘total’ to your first chart code)

Not my work, just what a peer showed me.